# Issue on Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-authentication

On my Intranet Web Application, I have enabled Windows Authentication. For the first time when I take the App, it asks for Windows Authentication. From there it will never ask. How can I know whether the authentication is happening on each refresh of my page after first attempt?

For example, if I tried to change my Windows password while the app is running, will the app prompt for password again on refresh?

Answer (score 3):

The authentication happens when you first connect. The server knows who the user is and is able to keep them logged in. If the user changes the password it will not ask them to re-authenticate until they close out the browser. This is due to the fact they already have an authentication and that will stay there until their session is done, usually by closing all instances of a browser (multiple windows of the same browser can share the same memory for things like cookies and authentication)

Think of it this way. You go into your home after you unlock the front  door. You don't have to do this again until you leave your home. You can change your lock while you are home and still be in your home without having to unlock it again until you come back.

Comment: Thanks Mark, but is there any way in IIS level or through web.config so that authentication happens each time.

Comment: Not that I've ever found and users would quickly avoid any app that required them to keep logging in, which is what would have to happen. Keep in mind, authentication and authorization are two different things. No user wants to be forced to authenticate their credentials all the time. Picture logging into your computer, and every action you performed required you to enter your credentials again. Authentication should only happen once during a user session.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable update Mark. But what is happening with my app is described below. 
My website first authenticate then will not ask for authentication if browser is not closed or password doesn't changed.
If password changed while the website is running, then on refresh for the first time it ask for authentication. Only for the first time.Then even the password is changed for second time and the browser is not yet closed from first attempt, it ask for authentication after a few interval only. may be 2-3 min.

Comment: Mark, I assume that a Windows web app could destroy the session cookie every few minutes if it wished to? For high-security applications e.g. in banking, there may be value in this.